# How to pass parameters into callback function in C++?

Tags: c++, callback

In OpenSSL there is a method

```
void SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb(SSL_CTX *ctx, int (*client_cert_cb)(SSL *ssl, X509 **x509, EVP_PKEY **pkey));
```

It registers callback function in security context. That callback function has a number of input parameters. How should I properly pass these parameters to the function?

Callback function definition is like that

```
int ClientCertCallback(SSL* ssl, X509** x509, EVP_PKEY** pkey)
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

What should be proper call to the registering function? So far I am calling it just like that

```
SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb(ctx, ClientCertCallback);
```

But how should I add parameters to callback function in the line above?

Comment: *"how should I add parameters to callback function"*. Which parameters do you want to add?

Comment: I want to be sure when callback triggers, it uses proper values of parameters (SSL* ssl, X509** x509, EVP_PKEY** pkey). From where does callback function takes them if I did not mention it in SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb(ctx, ClientCertCallback);?

Comment: Registered function is called my the library, and the library provides the arguments. From the name, function should be called when certificate is "received".

Comment: Are you sure it is getting “incorrect” parameters? Why don’t you pass in your own callback function that (1) prints out the parameters and (2) calls the default function? Then you’ll know what is given to the callback. Or just look for the call site in OpenSSL’s code based on the argument name and check where the parameters come from.